Reattaching light to house (brick)?
My kid hit this light with her ball and it came loose from the side of the house.
I would like to reattach the grey junction box to the house and or/cover the hole in some way and install a new light (My replacement light has a similar trapezoidal base to the current one).
The light was installed by the previous owner.
These (green) don't look like brick anchors to my eyes but I could be wrong.
See any issue with finding different anchors and throwing the box back up there? or would you do something different?



The existing holes in the brick have split so you would need to fill with resin or similar, then redrill and use suitable anchors.
However, I see the metal conduit box offering two ears which are normally threaded. So some suitable screws and washers might provide a better support, or even extra support for the lamp compared to the brick alone.
Then a grille or protection around / over the lamp may stop it being a future target...
